# Connect Oracle 11g using PHP 5.3.5 from XAMPP 1.7.4 on Windows XP 3 32 bit

Tags: php, oracle11g, xampp, database-connection, environment-variables

I am trying to connect my remote Oracle 11g database on Windows 2003 using PHP from XAMPP on my 32 bit Windows operating system. I have gone through many tutorials, blog, and videos. I tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMhkD43yUzI by 1niko2niko

What I did,

Installed  XAMPP 1.7.4 32 bit on my **C:\xampp**

```
;extension=php_oci8.dll => extension=php_oci8.dll
```

(removed semicolon) fron php.ini located inside **C:\xampp\php**

downloaded Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.4.0 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html and extracted to **C:\instantclient_11_2**

My Computer => Right Click => Properties => Advanced => Environment Variables => System Vairables  => Edit => Path => C:\instantclient_11_2\ => Ok => OK => Ok

PHP connection string I found on internet:

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('user','pass','111.111.111.111/sid');
// Prepare the statement
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM  names');
if (!$stid) {
$e = oci_error($conn);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
// Perform the logic of the query
$r = oci_execute($stid);
if (!$r) {
$e = oci_error($stid);
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
// Fetch the results of the query
print "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
print "<tr>\n";
foreach ($row as $item) {
    print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item,ENT_QUOTES)    : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
}
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
?>
```

I tried this process under Win XP, Win 7 using virtual box.

Restarted my computer and shows the following result

```
Warning: oci_connect() [function.oci-connect]: OCIEnvNlsCreate() failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client libraries in C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\index.php on line 3

Warning: oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\index.php on line 6

Warning: oci_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\index.php on line 8

Fatal error: in C:\xampp\htdocs\oracle\index.php on line 9
```

Comment: best answer i can give, is use the latest versions of all, use latest xampp https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html , download latest oracle instant client i have mentioned above, and use windows 7 OS and follow the same process as mentioned above and hey you also need to uncomment the line php_oci8-11g.dll